# How to show full list of selectable year in Jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

How can I show full selectable list of years when i clicked the year dropdownlist.

There is example in below link.In example when i clicked the year dropdownlist. It show just 10 years.when i select the first year(2000), the list is changing and i can see 1990 year in list.How can I show full selectable list of years?
Thanks for any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/t7rkk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked your fiddle and modified it with a new `yearRange` parameter:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/Tcnfq/

```
$("#datet").datepicker({
        minDate:SetDate('-100y'),
        maxDate:SetDate('+0d'),
        firstDay: 1,
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeYear: true,
   -->  yearRange: 'c-100,c+00' <--
    });
```

From [jQueryUI datepicker source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L77):

```
 yearRange: 'c-10:c+10', // Range of years to display in drop-down,
            // either relative to today's year (-nn:+nn), relative to currently displayed year
            // (c-nn:c+nn), absolute (nnnn:nnnn), or a combination of the above (nnnn:-n)
```

You set `minDate` as `('-100y')`, that's why I used `c-100` (current minus 100).

You set `maxDate` as `('+0d')`, that's why I used `c+00` (current plus zero).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datet").datepicker({
            minDate:SetDate('-1000y'),// simply change this value to 
            maxDate:SetDate('+0d'),// and this if you wanna go more into future dates
            firstDay: 1,
            changeMonth: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeYear: true,
        });


     });
```

Comment: i cannot see the full selectable year in list. that is not the correct answer that I expected.

Comment: what do you mean full selectable year?